# Please explain the format method in Python

Tags: python, format

Does anybody know what the `{0:>{1}}` means in the `print('{0:>{1}}'.format(num, width), end='')`

thank you very much

Comment: This question displays such a [lack of research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) that makes it likely to be closed as "too broad".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Just read through the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting). As @PauloScardine, says, you have put very little effort in. Come back when you've made a real attempt at the issue.